# Vector type String but when initialize with integer

Tags: c++, c++11

I have below code:

```
vector<string> v6{10};
cout << v6.size() << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << v6[i] << endl;      
}
```

Output is in the below picture:
http://i.prntscr.com/5f8e1fecbdd34fbc9c9d18b9e7e7a2a2.png

Why they print 10 for v6's size. I thought it creates a vector string with the first element is integer. And when I print all value it show something like space

Comment: For clarity - and might be worth adding to qu, what do you expect `vector<string> v6(10)` to do?, and by "space" do you mean empty string?

Answer (score 5):

`v6.size()` is the size of the vector.  You have created a vector of 10 empty strings.  If you look at `v6[0].size()`, for example, it will be zero.

You probably meant to do this:

```
vector<string> v6{ "10" };
```

By using an integer instead of a string literal, you called the vector constructor overload that means "create a vector of this many default-constructed elements," where you likely meant "create a vector with these specific elements."

Comment: also i would add links to docs regarding vector constructor: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: You could really do what the OP did and use `vector<string> v6{"10"};`. You could argue it's not worth the mental overhead due to the init-list constructor being chosen in some cases and not others, though.

Comment: @chris Ah, you are right, I forgot about the initializer list syntax.

Comment: Why doesn't the initializer list version give a compile error? I thought it used whatever was between `{` and `}` as "contents".

Comment: @doctorlove [List initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) can also be used to invoke any constructor. *"If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed."* `{ 10 }` did not match `std::initializer_list<string>` and so the non init-list constructors were then considered.